# Difference between likelihood and marginal likelihood and why the second is used inBayesian model selection to avoid overfitting

Tags: bayesian, modeling, model-selection, likelihood, overfitting

In Bayesian Model selection we integrate the likelihood and choose the model that maximize this quantity also called marginal likelihood , in order to protect us from overfitting. What is the conceptual difference between likelihood and marginal likelihood and why the second one should protect me from overfitting?

Comment: The quick explanation is that. the larger the space, the more fraction of said space is not providing a good fit of the data. Hence the notion of marginal likelihood as an automatic Ockham's razor.